# JQuery Animate does not work

Tags: jquery, html

I'am trying to copy the following code into my project:

https://codepen.io/colorlib/pen/rxddKy

```
<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
      <button>create</button>
      <p class="message">Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

And now this is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/39uho033/

```
<body>

        <div class="login-page">
            <div class="form">
                <form class="register-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
                    <button>
                        create
                    </button>
                    <p class="message">
                        Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a>
                    </p>
                </form>
                <form class="login-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
                    <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                    <button>
                        login
                    </button>
                    <p class="message">
                        Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script>


        </script>

    </body>
```

But why this isnt working? If I click on "Create an account" the register-form isnt showing (by the animate function).

Please visit the links for the whole code!

Comment: Have you link jquery in head?

Comment: ur fiddle and also your code need ref. of jquery

Comment: Yes. I've added this to the head: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Check your console, it says cannot recognize '$' -> Which indicates Jquery hasn't been linked to

Comment: You can add JQuery through the *External resources* option on the left of JS Fiddle. I think it rejects some head tag imports for security purposes. so if u add it there instead it might work in JSFiddle. Do you have this issue on ur local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include the jQuery external resource in you jsfiddle. your code works fine.

Your JSFIDDLE after including

`jQuery.min.js`

https://jsfiddle.net/39uho033/7/

Comment: same thing I thought. nice one linking the revised JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

```js
$('.message a').click(function() {

    $('form').animate({
     height : "toggle",
     opacity : "toggle"
    }, "slow");
   });
```

```css
 @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);

  .h1 {
   font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
   color: #4CAF50;
   text-decoration: none;
  }
  .login-page {
   width: 360px;
   padding: 8% 0 0;
   margin: auto;
  }
  .form {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
   background: #FFFFFF;
   max-width: 360px;
   margin: 0 auto 100px;
   padding: 45px;
   text-align: center;
   box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  }
  .form input {
   font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
   outline: 0;
   background: #f2f2f2;
   width: 100%;
   border: 0;
   margin: 0 0 15px;
   padding: 15px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-size: 14px;
  }
  .form button {
   font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   outline: 0;
   background: #4CAF50;
   width: 100%;
   border: 0;
   padding: 15px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 14px;
   -webkit-transition: all 0.3 ease;
   transition: all 0.3 ease;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  .form button:hover, .form button:active, .form button:focus {
   background: #43A047;
  }
  .form .message {
   margin: 15px 0 0;
   color: #b3b3b3;
   font-size: 12px;
  }
  .form .message a {
   color: #4CAF50;
   text-decoration: none;
  }
  .form .register-form {
   display: none;
  }
  .container {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
   max-width: 300px;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .container:before, .container:after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   clear: both;
  }
  .container .info {
   margin: 50px auto;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .container .info h1 {
   margin: 0 0 15px;
   padding: 0;
   font-size: 36px;
   font-weight: 300;
   color: #1a1a1a;
  }
  .container .info span {
   color: #4d4d4d;
   font-size: 12px;
  }
  .container .info span a {
   color: #000000;
   text-decoration: none;
  }
  .container .info span .fa {
   color: #EF3B3A;
  }
  body {
   background: #3BB9FF; /* fallback for old browsers */
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #3BB9FF, #3BB9FF);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #3BB9FF, #3BB9FF);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #3BB9FF, #3BB9FF);
   background: linear-gradient(to left, #3BB9FF, #3BB9FF);
   font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div class="login-page">
   <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form">
     <input type="text" placeholder="name"/>
     <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
     <input type="text" placeholder="email address"/>
     <button>
      create
     </button>
     <p class="message">
      Already registered? <a href="#">Sign In</a>
     </p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form">
     <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
     <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
     <button>
      login
     </button>
     <p class="message">
      Not registered? <a href="#">Create an account</a>
     </p>
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>

 
  <script>
     
 
  </script>

 </body>
```